# How to change order of rows in table based on list of rows id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have table with id `test_table`

```
<table id="test_table"> </table>
```

and or has different id.

I have ordered list of rows' id like

```
["name","value","description"]
```

what is different from rendered table on screen ( user can on fly set new order, that is how I fill list of rows' id).

How to set new order in that table based on ordered list ?
(Explanation:
I have two lists one aside other, user can drag and drop rows in first table and I need to have same order in second, ids in second table have same id like in first +prefix "preview".
This is how I drag/drop in first table. )

```
$("#cleanVert").tableDnD({
    onDragClass: "myDragClass",
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
        var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
        var debugStr = "New Order: ";
        var outStr = "";
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            debugStr += rows[i].id+" ";
            outStr += rows[i].id;
            if(i<(rows.length-1)){
                outStr+=","
            }
        }
        $("#debugArea").html(debugStr);
    },
    onDragStart: function(table, row) {
        $("#debugArea").html("Started dragging row "+row.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do a JS ajax call to a php script

Comment: How are your users able to reorder the list?  You need to show us some code of what you have and have tried in order for us to better help you.  We aren't going to write the code for you

Comment: you can use jQuery ui shortable

Comment: You haven't accepted an answer yet or asked any further/clarifying questions.  Have you solved your problem or do you still need some assistance?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after a client side table sorting, there's quite a few available online, it depends what javascript library you are familiar with. I have chosen to use a jQuery plugin called [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) and I am assuming based on your tags that it might be a good option for you too.

The downside to it is that it is client-side only, so If a user doesn't have Javascript enabled, they will not be able to sort the table, I'd say that is not a major problem, the average user always have Javascript enabled.

The other option is to build a server-side sorting, this can be as easy as adding

```
ORDER BY "$selectedField" "$order"
```

in your database query. It will also ensures that it works without Javascript.

Nowadays many of the popular web development frameworks provide that sort of feature, if you haven't discovered it yet, I encourage you to take a look at some options for your programming language.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to do everything in jQuery, which it looks like you are trying to do, then I would look into [jQuery Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) but if you want it to be like a link/button that sorts each field by say Ascending or Descending order, or by like usernames etc, and keep it server-side then what I would suggest is have the button/link reload itself with a sub-query in the url that would say something like `?order_by=asc` or `?order_by=username&dir=asc` then run a check for it on the page, passing that variable/sub-query ($_GET['order_by']) to a function.  In the function, do a query that looks similar to this:

```
$order_by = "ORDER BY " . $_GET['order_by'] . $_GET['dir'];
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM table
          $order_by";
```

You could then use this same query for the main page load (that hasn't been sorted) without difficulty using the variable, then when the query is re-run with a loaded `$order_by` then the list will be ordered by parameter.